# Реализация декоратора для прерываемой операции

Tags: python, асинхронность, декоратор

Я пытаюсь реализовать класс-декоратор, который сделает из функции класс Operation. Он представляет из себя задачу, которую можно приостановить, возобновить, отменить, и который сообщает о выполнении промежуточных операций и о полном завершении с помощью callback-функций.

Пример того, что я хочу добиться:

```
def concrete_callback(percent):
    # UI, log or something update
    ...

def concrete_done(result):
    # result and errors handling
    ...

# Оборачиваем произвольную функцию в декоратор, который принимает
# 1) коллбек, который отслеживает
#    состояние задачи (например, вызывает перерисовку progressbar)
# 2) коллбек, который функция должна дёрнуть по завершении (в идеале передав ей результат)
@Operation(concrete_callback, concrete_done)
def something_func(ar1, ar2):
    ...

suspend, resume, cancel = fun(2, 3) # функция начала выполняться в другом потоке

# Но я могу поставить её на паузу:
suspend()

# Снять с паузы:
resume()

# Отменить:
cancel()
```

В процессе реализации попытался использовать вместо функции [асинхронный генератор](https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/). По завершении каждой итерации, асинхронный генератор должен возвращать результат в `concrete_callback`. По завершении всех итераций, генератор должен дёрнуть `concrete_done` callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ок, я пришёл к этому решению (с демострацией вызова):

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
import asyncio
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def main():
    def concrete_callback(process):
        # UI, log or something update
        logger.info(f'Iteration complete with: {process}...')

    def concrete_done():
        # result and errors handling
        logger.info('All iterations complete!')
    
    class Operation:
        def __init__(self_operation, progress_callback, done_callback):
            self_operation.progress = progress_callback
            self_operation.done = done_callback

        @staticmethod
        def progress(*args, **kwargs):
            pass
        
        @staticmethod
        def done():
            pass

        def __call__(self_operation, cls):          
            class AsyncGeneratorWrapper():
                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    self.running = False
                    self.canceled = False
                    self._execute_queue = Queue(256)
                    self.generator = cls(*args, **kwargs)
                
                def __iter__(self):
                    # deconstruction hack for convenient syntax
                    self._execute_queue.put(self._step_execute_task)
                    yield from (self._run, self.suspend, self.cancel)

                async def _run(self):
                    self.running = True
                    try:
                        while True:
                            try:
                                task = self._execute_queue.get(block=False)
                            except Empty:
                                break
                            else:
                                if await task():
                                    break

                                self._execute_queue.task_done()
                    finally:
                        self.running = False

                async def __aenter__(self):
                    self._execute_queue.put(self._step_execute_task)
                    self.task = asyncio.create_task(self._run())
                    return self.suspend, self.cancel
                
                async def __aexit__(self, except_type, except_value, traceback):
                    await self.task
                
                async def _step_execute_task(self):
                    if not self.canceled:
                        try:
                            target = await (anext(self.generator))
                        except StopAsyncIteration:
                            self_operation.done()
                            return True
                        else:
                            self_operation.progress(target)
                        self._execute_queue.put(self._step_execute_task)

                async def _suspend_task(self):
                    if not self.canceled:
                        if self.running:
                            logger.debug('Suspend!')

                            # break _run loop
                            return True
                        else:
                            raise self.InvalidOperationStateError('Operation is not running.', self)
                    else:
                        raise self.InvalidOperationStateError('Operation is canceled.', self)
                
                def suspend(self):
                    self._execute_queue.put(self._suspend_task)
                    return self.resume
                
                def _resume_task(self):
                    if not self.canceled:
                        if not self.running:
                            self._execute_queue.put(self._step_execute_task)
                            logger.debug('Resume!')
                            return self._run
                        else:
                            raise self.InvalidOperationStateError('Operation in progress', self)
                    else:
                        raise self.InvalidOperationStateError('Operation is canceled.', self)

                def resume(self):
                    self._execute_queue.put(self._resume_task())
                    return self._run()
                
                async def _cancel_task(self):
                    if not self.canceled:
                        self.canceled = True
                        logger.debug('Cancel!')
                        
                        # break tasks
                        try:
                            while True:
                                _ = self._execute_queue.get(block=False)
                                self._execute_queue.task_done()
                        except Empty:
                            pass
                    else:
                        raise self.InvalidOperationStateError('Operation is canceled.', self)

                def cancel(self):
                    self._execute_queue.put(self._cancel_task)
                
                class InvalidOperationStateError(RuntimeError):
                    '''Raised when an operation enters an invalid state'''
                    pass

            return AsyncGeneratorWrapper

    @Operation(progress_callback=concrete_callback, done_callback=concrete_done)
    class AsyncGenerator:
        def __init__(self, start, stop):
            self.current = start
            self.start = start
            self.stop = stop
    
        def __aiter__(self):
            return self
    
        async def __anext__(self):
            if self.current < self.stop:
                self.current += 1
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                return self.current
            else:
                raise StopAsyncIteration
    
    async def simulate_pause(suspend_callback):
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # get asynchronously resume callback and suspend operation
        resume_callback = suspend_callback()
        # wait
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # comeback
        await resume_callback()
    
    async def simulate_stop(cancel_callback):
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
        cancel_callback()
    
    # Examples

    async with AsyncGenerator(0, 5) as (suspend, cancel):
        logger.info('__')
        logger.info('ContextManager: Test Suspend, Resume')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # get asynchronously resume callback and suspend operation
        resume_callback = suspend()
        # wait
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # comeback
        await resume_callback()
    
    async with AsyncGenerator(0, 5) as (suspend, cancel):
        logger.info('__')
        logger.info('ContextManager: Test Suspend only')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        # get asynchronously resume callback and suspend operation
        resume_callback = suspend()
    
    async with AsyncGenerator(0, 5) as (suspend, cancel):
        logger.info('__')
        logger.info('ContextManager: Test Cancel')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        cancel()
    
    async with AsyncGenerator(0, 5) as (suspend, cancel):
        logger.info('__')
        logger.info('ContextManager: Test run other code')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('text printed')

    async with AsyncGenerator(0, 5) as (suspend, cancel):
        logger.info('__')
        logger.info('ContextManager: Test run only without control')

    logger.info('__')
    logger.info('Without ContextManager: Test Suspend, Resume, Cancel:')

    run1, suspend1, cancel1 = AsyncGenerator(0, 10)
    _ = await asyncio.wait([asyncio.create_task(coro) for coro in [run1(), simulate_pause(suspend1), simulate_stop(cancel1)]])

    logger.info('__')
    logger.info('Without ContextManager: Run only without control:')
    run2, *_ = AsyncGenerator(0, 5)
    await run2()

    logger.info('__')
    logger.info('main done')

asyncio.run(main())
```

---

Потокобезопасен ли декоратор `Operation`?
Насколько плох текущий код?

Comment: Почему никто не отвечает на этот вопрос? Что с ним не так?

Comment: Если вы про ответ, то на него никто и не ответит, потому что это ответ, а не вопрос. Если нужна инспекция кода, то нужно задать отдельный вопрос. Не сильно углубляясь в код могу сказать, что не нужно все вносить в main - там должен быть только запускающий код, а не все классы и функции.

Comment: Еще, навскидку, AsyncGenerator можно просто через функцию реализовать. Декоратор тоже скорее всего через функции можно переписать.

Comment: То что декоратор неявно превращает асинхронный итератор в менеджер контекста и вообще меняет способ возврата значения - это какая-то излишняя магия. Итератор вообще может быть не вашей функцией, вам тогда придется писать функцию-обертку, и к ней добавлять декоратор. Тут удобнее вместо декоратора использовать просто функцию-менеджер контекста.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Comment: Ну это не ответы по сути, это комментарии, максимум - советы. Лучше задать отдельный вопрос, тогда можно будет более-менее полный ответ.